# Domain not responding to A record

Tags: domain, subdomain, nameserver

I had domain set to amazon EC2 instance. Yesterday decided to switch to the DO dedicated server, changed A record of domain to the DO server ip address. It's started to work pretty fast(less than 10 minutes).

Today my domain is not available, why so?

Here is dig output:

```
dig domain.com                                                                                                                                       

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> domain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 28571
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;domain.com.            IN  A

;; Query time: 2261 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sun Dec 14 13:19:47 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 29
```

P.S. I also added A record for stage.domain.com subdomain to another DO instance for staging, can this affect availability somehow?

Comment: Notice that the name servers are returning SERVFAIL (rather than NXDOMAIN) so there's something broken - probably the data for your domain. What happens if you try querying the name servers where your DNS is hosted directly?

Comment: Please use dig +trace and post the unredacted outpout.